# MySQL Sorting a table by frequently updated column and Pagination

Tags: mysql, pagination, innodb

I am stuck in a problem where I have to sort a mysql table via a column which is updated very frequently (likes, points etc) and paginate it, I can't use the simple limit based approach because it is quite possible when user reaches second page the sort order has been changed due to changing values of likes, I have read on internet to use the cursor based approach but all the examples demonstrating that are using some fixed column, like ID or date time. And that doesn't server the purpose.

I am currently getting the shown ids from user and using them in a NOT IN condition to not select the previously shown records but that solution doesn't feel right in terms of speed and optimisations.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If your result set is small enough, then you could send the whole table over and handle pagination client-side with something like datatables.net

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the table I dealing with has around 900k rows.

Comment: There is no non-confusing solution. However, the larger the number of likes the less likely a frequently and majorly changing order becomes.

Comment: @Jakumi, not sure I completely understand what you said, can you please explain a bit? Thanks

Comment: One relatively easy idea would be to do snapshots of the rankings and make the user carry the timestamp of the last snapshot around until they decide to update. If no user uses an older snapshot, you can safely delete it. However, 900k rows is quite the snapshot ;o/

Comment: What I meant is ... the bigger the number of likes are ... the bigger the differences between items get. Like first item has 1000 votes next item 950 and so on ... that order won't change much on the first few pages. But from a certain point, it's hard to keep things ordered for a longer time, except if you somehow "freeze" time. (snapshots) So the question is, what is the time you want the table to freeze? And for users that are slightly slower, it will be confusing if it changes unexpectedly. There is no "silver bullet" for this ...

Answer (score 0):

First, move the "frequently updated column" into another, parallel, table.  This will make the system more efficient by avoiding the conflict with updating "likes" versus touching the rest of the columns.

Such a table would have only 2 columns -- `id` (for `JOINing` with the main table) and `likes`.  Now you are poised to do the "remember where you left off" approach to pagination.  (`OFFSET` would be really bad for this.)

But keep track of two things to remember where you left off:  $leftoff_id, $leftoff_likes.  Assuming you want "descending":

```
PRIMARY KEY(likes, id) -- for this query
INDEX(id, likes) -- for maintenance and JOINs

SELECT likes
    From Likes
    WHERE likes <= $leftoff_likes
      AND ( id < $leftoff_id OR likes < $leftoff_likes )
    ORDER BY likes DESC, id DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

(I use `id DESC` since MySQL cannot use an index for `ORDER BY x DESC, y ASC`.)